# Oracle SQL append column by same values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

table1:

| name | age | weight | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 20 | 105 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| c | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| d |  | 15 | 110 |

table2

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| a | foo |
| b | bar |
| c |  |
| d |  |

I would like to append the column id from table_2 if the value of the column name is identical:

| name | age | weight | height | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 20 | 105 | foo |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 | bar |
| c | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| d |  | 15 | 110 |  |

How to merge these two tables by keeping all rows of table1?

Comment: Looks like a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: BTW, never store age. People become older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store DOB instead.

Comment: This is called `join`. Please post your current code and describe what the issue you have. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.name,T.age,T.weight,T.height,X.id
FROM TABLE_1 T
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 X ON T.name=X.name
```

you can use LEFT JOIN , as suggested in the first comment

Comment: Using a asterisk for the first table such as `SELECT t1.*, t2.id` along with aliases `t1`, `t2` would be more more proper I think...